# Authentication required. The server requires a username and password

Tags: asp.net, url, iis

I have an authenticated user. When he clicks on a link

```
http://mydomain/myFolder/test@gmail.com/filename.pdf
```

Browser opens a window with authentication required message.

> Authentication required. The server   http://mydomain:80 requires a username and password.

This was  excellent working on my local machine. On click pdf opens normally. 
So can you help me solve the problem on server?

Comment: I found the solution, here it is.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664155/why-browser-url-cannot-end-with-com